# How can I fetch number from string to substring and keep in array?

Tags: java

I have number in string. I want to cut and keep into array by loop or any way
and then bring this array to loop again to be rank from least to most.
How the way to have result same like these array I build.
Thank You.

```
public class Main
{
    static String input = "1,3,7,11,5,16,13,12,22,14";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       /*
        int[] keep = new int[11]; //How I can know if I don't know total index in first time.`enter code here`
        keep[0] = 1;
        keep[1] = 3;
        keep[2] = 7;
        keep[3] = 11;
        keep[4] = 5;
        keep[5] = 16;
        keep[6] = 13;
        keep[7] = 12;
        keep[8] = 22;
        keep[9] = 14;

        int[] rank = new int[keep.length];
        rank[0] = 1;
        rank[1] = 3;
        rank[2] = 5;
        rank[3] = 7;
        rank[4] = 11;
        rank[5] = 12;
        rank[6] = 13;
        rank[7] = 14;
        rank[8] = 16;
        rank[9] = 22;
        */

        for (int i=0;i<rank.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(rank[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your description is very obscure. Do I undertsand you correct that you want to convert this String into an array of integers? If so you could start by checking out the `split` method of string.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `split` method on your input string then convert from `String` to `integer`

```
String[] splitted=input.split(",");

int[] keep = new int[splitted.length];

for(int i=0;i<splitted.length;i++){
    keep[i]= Integer.parseInt(splitted[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can:

- split the string to colon
- stream that resulting array
- map that to integer parsing each element in the array
- turn the result into an array

so basically:

```
String input = "1,3,7,11,5,16,13,12,22,14";
int[] foo = Stream.of(input.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foo));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
String input = "1,3,7,11,5,16,13,12,22,14";

String[] keepStrings = input.split(",");
int[] keep = new int[keepStrings.length];
int[] rank = new int[keep.length];// create a rank array

// arrays can be duplicated only by doing field by field copy. Otherwise it may lead to aliasing.
for (int i = 0; i < keepStrings.length; i++) {
    keep[i] = Integer.parseInt(keepStrings[i]);
    rank[i] = keep[i];
}

Arrays.sort(rank);

System.out.println(keep); //[1, 3, 7, 11, 5, 16, 13, 12, 22, 14]
System.out.println(rank); //[1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 22]
```